# ResourceString VS Const for string literals

Tags: performance, string, delphi, optimization, resources

I have a couple of thousands string literals in a Delphi application. They have been isolated in a separate file and used for localization in the past.

Now I don't need localization any more.

Is there any performance penalty in using resourcestring compared to plain constants.

Should I change those to CONST instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The const string makes a call to `_UStrLAsg` and the resource string ends up in `LoadResString`.

Since the question is about speed there is nothing like doing a test.

```
resourcestring
    str2 = 'str2';

const
    str1 = 'str1';

function ConstStr1: string;
begin
    result := str1;
end;

function ReceStr1: string;
begin
    result := str2;
end;

function ConstStr2: string;
begin
    result := str1;
end;

function ReceStr2: string;
begin
    result := str2;
end;

procedure Test;
var
    s1, s2, s3, s4: string;
begin
    s1 := ConstStr1;
    s2 := ReceStr1;
    s3 := ConstStr2;
    s4 := ReceStr2;
end;
```

For the first time I used AQTime added in DelphiXE to profile this code and here is the result. The time column show Machine Cycles.

[image: Report from AQTime]

I might have done a lot of rookie mistakes profiling this but as I see it there is a difference between `const` and `resourcestring`. If the difference is noticeable for a user depends on what you do with the string. In a loop with many iterations it can matter but used to display information to the users, not so much.

Comment: +1 because you use timing, not just "guess" like others. LoadString and FindResourceHInstance API calls are not immediate. That's why we implemented an internal caching mechanism inside our enhanced implementation of LoadResString in our [enhanced RTL](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=6) for Delphi 7, and also a caching in our `resourcestring` automated translation for [the i18n unit](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3i18n.pas) of our framework. As you wrote, in a loop, such caching DO make a difference! Use a local temp string is a good practice in such a loop.

Comment: @A.Bouchez Timing is good, but easy to mislead. This is micro-benchmarking. Put it in a real program which presumably doesn't spend 100% of its time reading these strings and you'll often find that you can't tell the difference. So yes there is a performance difference but it's simply impossible to know whether or not it matters in the context of OP's app.

Comment: @Mikael @A.Bouchez Plus the timing results look decidedly dubious. Why do ConstStr1 and ConstStr2 have such different times? And how was the benchmarking done? Need more detail!

Comment: @David There is a difference between the first time the const/resourcestring is accessed and the second time. Why there is a difference I do not know but the first call is a lot slower than the rest. That is why I included two calls to the test. The time difference between ConstStr1 and ReceStr1 is not important.

Comment: @Mikael I don't believe there is very much value in this micro-benchmark. I think you need to time the real app.

Comment: @David No Benchmark is ever absolute, but I wanted to salute at least an attempt to use a clock instead of just guessing. About performance, I've already benchmarked, in real application, how using a local temporary string in a loop is faster than direct resourcestring use. Why the first call is slower does make sense: the resource content must be accessed for the first time, Windows must calculate the offset in the memory mapped exe, then create a PChar from it. I guess Windows itself is using some internal caching, so later call are faster. Here I'm guessing, since Windows is a black box :)

Comment: @David Of course you're right: in a real application with no loop, there will be no noticeable difference between a const and a resourcestring.

Comment: @A.Bouchez I think we are in agreement then. I agree that timing is the only way to answer performance questions definitively. I just wanted to flag up that it can be very difficult to do so.

Comment: @Apalala - No, it is not cached. Just step through the code and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are stored in a single file which presumably does little else (well done!), there's no reason not to try it out. I predict it won't make any discernible difference to performance, but I guess it depends on what else you are doing in your app.

Answer (score -1):

Resource strings do incur overhead.

Compared to displaying such a string, or writing it to a file or database, the overhead is not much.

On the other hand it is just a switch from the `resourcestring` to `const` keyword (and back if you ever consider to to localization again).

Comment: Take a look at LoadResString implementation in System.pas: it's not two extra pointer redirections, but at least two calls to the Windows API: LoadString and FindResourceHInstance. Even if resources are mapped in memory, those API are not immediate. Then a string creation from the returned PChar content. The "two pointer redirections" you are talking about is not used with resourcestring - and it will also include a string creation from the PChar buffer.

Comment: Funny, I thought they were cached after the first fetch. Thanks for teaching me otherwise.